# Cannot find module 'express' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

Here's how it's displaying when i run command : npm run build

```
(node:600) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at C:\Users\DELL\devtachom-main\node_modUpdate this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Loaded env from C:\Users\DELL\devtachom-main\.env
Failed to compile.

./lib/index.ts:1:52
Type error: Cannot find module 'express' or its corresponding type declarations.

> 1 | import express, { Request, Response, Router } from "express";
    |                                                    ^
  2 | import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
  3 | import compression from "compression";
  4 | import cors from "cors";
info  - Creating an optimized production build .
PS C:\Users\DELL\devtachom-main>
```

i'm trying to run the project with vs code but it's giving me this dead end. Anyone who knows what needs to be done here, please help.

Comment: have you done `npm install --save-dev @types/express`?

Comment: yes i have tried this